# UITextView Moves to Left on Keyboard Show

Tags: swift, uikit

I have an app with a build target of IOS 14 that is causing a problem regarding automatic positioning of the view on keyboard show.

I have a UITextView that is draggable and can be positioned partially outside of the main view that it sits within. If the field is large enough then it will extend beyond the parent view and safe area also. The parent view has clipsToBounds set as true so the overflow of the text view is not visible.

The problem is when the text field is positioned so that its right hand side is outside of the safe area and the keyboard is presented, the screen automatically scrolls left to include the far right edge of the text view, even though it is not visible due to clipsToBounds being set on its parent. I need to disable the behaviour that is causing this to happen but can't find anything that covers this for UIKit.

See below for a visual example. Can anybody please help?

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8e55M.jpg)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmRBQ.jpg)

Edit:

The structure of the screen is:

View Controller:

.....UICollectionView:

..........UICollectionViewCell:

...............UIView:

....................Elements (UITextView in this case)

```
func calculateCarouselOffset(formHeight: CGFloat) -> CGAffineTransform {
    let carouselOffset: CGAffineTransform!
    let currentElementMaxY = returnCurrentElementMaxY()
    let elementMaxYTransformRemoved = currentElementMaxY + -self.scalingCarousel.transform.ty
    let newFormOriginY = safeAreaFrame.height - formHeight
    let topOfFormMargin: CGFloat = 20

    if (newFormOriginY - topOfFormMargin) < elementMaxYTransformRemoved {
        // Form will overlap element - move carousel view to compensate
        let oldToNewLocDist = (newFormOriginY - topOfFormMargin) - currentElementMaxY
        let moveScreenBy = self.scalingCarousel.transform.ty + oldToNewLocDist
        carouselOffset = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: moveScreenBy)
    } else {
        // Form will not overlap element - reset carousel view
        carouselOffset = self.formDeactivate
    }
    
    return carouselOffset
}
```

And it is called as below:

```
func textViewDidChage() {
    let backgorundTransform = calculateCarouselOffset(formHeight: currentElementFormHeight)
    let modifyBackground = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 0.2, curve: .linear, animations: {
        self.scalingCarousel.transform = backgorundTransform
    })
    modifyBackground.startAnimation()
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you've built the screen? I presume a UIScrollView is involved somewhere. Do you have code for making sure the text field is visible when the software keyboard appears?

Comment: @jrturton have posted additional info as requested

Comment: @jrtuton - Yes I have bespoke code for handling the vertical visibility side of the keyboard overlap. This all works fine.

Comment: Can you show that code, the problem is highly likely to be there. Or if you disable it, what happens?

Comment: The code is a bit too complex to post here. Hundreds of lines as elements are loaded in from DB into arrays, positioned via a bespoke subclass of UIView etc. You asked if I disable it what happens? That's what I'm trying to work out how to do. How can I disable the behaviour?

Comment: Ah sorry. I've just worked out you were referring to the bespoke Keyboard handling code. I have updated the question.

Comment: It seems the horizontal shift is independent to my vertical shift code. My code runs as expected then after it completes the text view animates left until its right side is within the safe area.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is (possibly new?) built-in behaviour for text fields. I reproduced this both with a collection view controller and a view controller holding a collection view. The text field moves itself to visible like this:

[image]

I found this by adding a symbolic breakpoint on `contentOffset` and then making a field editable - there are a lot of calls before you get to this point because it's also adjusting things for the keyboard coming up.

Unfortunately in your case, I think the scroll view is moving the text field's visible bounds into the visible area, which means you're scrolling horizontally since the text field is off screen.

You can't override `scrollTextFieldToVisibleIfNecessary` as it is private API. There are probably some hacks you can do by overriding `becomeFirstResponder` but they seem quite likely to either not work, or break other things.

Comment: jrturton - Thanks for this. I came to the same conclusion after more testing at this end. I have managed to apply a dirty fix that reverses any scrollview offset that is added by if the scroll is triggered by the textview. It's hacky but it works for now.